# Eliminar duplicados adyacentes de una lista en HASKELL

Tags: lista, haskell

Pues me gustaría crear una función en Haskell que me permitiese eliminar enteros **duplicados adyacentes** de una lista. La verdad he conseguido hacerlo para duplicados en toda la lista y aun así siempre se me queda el último dígito si aparecer:

```hs
    elimDups :: [Int] -> [Int]

    elimDups [] = []
    elimDups [_] = []

    elimDups (x:y:xs) = if x == y then elimDups(y:xs) else [x] ++ elimDups(y:xs)
```

Usado me queda así:

```hs
elimDups [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1]
[1,2,3]
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es esto:

```hs
elimDups[1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1]
[1,2,3,1]
```

Comment: Porque escribe `elimDups [_] = []`, si la lista contiene solo un elemento, ud. ignora el elemento y tratarlo como una lista vacia. Por favor cambiar el codigo a: `elimDups [a] = [a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te paso una forma de hacerlo:

```
eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes::[Int]->[Int]
eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes [] = []
eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes [x] = [x]
eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes (x:xs)
    | x == head xs  = eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes xs
    | otherwise = x:eliminarRepetidosAdyacentes xs;
```

Funciona asi:

Llega hasta el ultimo elemento de la lista ( caso base ),cuando vuelve hacia atras por que termino la recursion,pregunta si el anterior es igual a el que vuelve.

En caso positivo no lo agrega , si son diferentes si.

Espero que te haya servido.

Un abrazo.

Comment: Sirvió muchas gracias